# Is arduino suitable for high frequency application?

Tags: serial

Can I use the arduino for an application with a frequency of 4 MHz?

I need to create a clk with this frequency and send and receive data on the rising and falling edges. and it is not a normal SPI interface I have my own conditions so I need to do it manually.

If it is not suitable, is it technically possible?

Comment: How can we tell you whether an AVR can speak the protocol you need, if you don't tell us what that protocol is?

Answer (score 1):

Most Arduinos are based on AVR chips clocked at 16 MHz. On those,
you *can* generate a 4 MHz clock using hardware timers. Bit-banging
data at this speed would be difficult though. It *may* be possible,
using unrolled loops and hand-crafted assembly... or not, depending on
the specifics of your application. Even if possible, it would be a nice
challenge for an assembly programmer.

The Arduino Due is based on an ARM chip clocked at 84 MHz. This
gives you more leeway to bit-bang at 4 MHz. But even on the Due you
would certainly need hand-crafted assembly.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not suitable due to the inherent maximum pin output frequencies in relation to the clock divider setting.

Yes, it's technically possible. Edit the divider to a value that sets the output to close to what you need. However this is annoying to do, and has serious repercussions in your code. (i.e. having to multiply every timing/bit value by 16, 8, 4, 2 or whatever you choose)

A clock of that high of a frequency would have to be some crystal to set the base time, and then a comparator circuit that could vary fast enough to push data into the edges.

You could, however, simply note the absence of the 4MHz signal as 0, and it's presence as 1, sending binary data that way it probably a lot easier than encoding it between each individual edge.